# When limits preserve projectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, projective-module

Are there examples of rings $R$ with nonzero global dimension over which  inverse limits of projectives are projective?

If not, are there any $R$'s over which products of projectives are projective (equivalently, $R^{\Bbb N}$ projective)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A theorem of Chase states that projective (right) $R$-modules are closed under arbitrary products if and only if $R$ is right perfect and left coherent.

If (and only if) $R$ also has global dimension at most two, then projective modules are also closed under kernels, and hence under arbitrary limits.

If by inverse limits you mean only directed limits, there may be more examples, but I don’t know.

Comment: Thanks! After good sleep, I've cooked up several (obvious) artinian examples; but right perfect left coherent ring looks for me very close to artinian — am I right that in commutative case those conditions are equivalent? — so what's in the gap?

Comment: As for inverse limits, I'd be happy to understand conditions (maybe on both ring and ideal) under which projectives are closed under adic completion, but I have a feeling that it's bad question (in a sense that no good answer exists).

Comment: @xsnl Yes, for commutative rings, perfect and coherent implies artinian.